# Prolog CSPs: Less than constraint with instantiated counters

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming

Using Eclipse prolog and assuming I have a variable X and X must be less than a known number N. For this i can write:

```
X #< N
```

So, whenever X gets instantiated to a number larger than N the suspended predicate above fails.

But that if i have a counter C that starts from 0, increases during search and  fails if it surpasses N?

For example what if I want to track the number of times a value is selected from a domain and the constraint is to never exceed N times. I can't do the above because Counter C gets instantiated to 0 and uses other variables for the incrementation (C1 is C+1).

do I have to do it with pure prolog? Something like this:

```
pred(X, N):- X1 is X+1, X1<N, pred(X1, N)
```

Comment: I hoped for the constraint library to do this (X1<N) check regularly for me.  is there another way with constraint programming?

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you want to formulate a true constraint (i.e. a condition involving a constant N, which has to hold for every solution), or whether you are looking for a way to heuristically curtail search (possibly losing valid solutions). Can you clarify, or give a concrete example?

Comment: Perhaps, I didn't explain it well. What I was looking for is eventually a cardinality constraint -.- . I was using the ic library and totally forgot there is ic-global as well where all these constraints are implemented..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here. I found what I was looking for. It's a cardinality constraint and is implemented in the ic global library of eclipse prolog.